# How to create a collection and iterator which go through certain values until its reaches one?

Tags: java, iterator, treemap

I have a `TreeMap<Token, ArrayList<Token>>` and I want to iterate through the map until a specific key which fulfills a requirement. I know that the following works for getting the values of a map:

```
Collection c = bigrams.values();
Iterator itr = c.iterator();

while (itr.hasNext()){
    System.out.println(itr.next());
```

However, I want to be able to iterate through the map with the keys linked to the iterator, and check each value based on its pair key. Since `bigrams.values()` retrieves the value of each of the elements of the bigram, how may I change this to retrieve the keys instead of the values?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit cryptic, but if you want to get the keys, you can simply use the `keySet()` method:

```
Collection c = test.keySet();
```

If you want to iterate through the map based on the keys, you can do:

```
for (Token key: bigrams.keySet()) {
    ArrayList<Token> list = bigrams.get(key);
    // do with the list what you want to do with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should eilter use [`Map.keySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#keySet()) or [`Map.entrySet()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()):

`Map.keySet()` returns a set containing all keys of your map. You then can use [`Map.get()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) to get the value for a given key:

```
for (Token key: bigrams.keySet()) {
    List<Token> list = bigrams.get(key);
    System.out.println(key + ": " + list);
}
```

`Map.entrySet()` returns a set of all pairs in your map, so there is no need to use `Map.get()` with this:

```
for (Map.Entry<Token, List<Token>> entry : bigrams.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Finally you also can use the Java Stream API for this. You also can use it to filter the content very easily. For example to find all tokens containing a given token in their value list:

```
bigrams.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getValue().contains(tokenToFind))
        .forEach(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue()));
```